# .append() overwriting existing in python

Tags: python, append, overwrite

```
from copy import copy

import os

print(os.getcwd())

os.chdir(f"C:\\Users\\{os.getlogin()}\\Desktop\\playarea")

print(os.getcwd())

for r, d, f in os.walk(os.getcwd()):

    for files in f:
        print(files)
        a = []
        temp = " "
        for i in range(0,len(files)):
            if files[i] == ".":
                temp = copy(files[i:])
                print(temp)
                print(a)
            
                if temp not in a:
                    a.append(temp)
print(a)
```

This above code exits output [".txt"] and i expect the output to be [".java",".js",".php",."py",".txt"] the append is overwriting why is this happening how do i solve this problem?

Comment: At each iteration, you reset ``a`` to ``[]``. Either initialize ``a`` outside the for loops, or place your print statement at the end of the ``for files in f:`` loop.

Answer (score 2):

Define the variable 'a' outside the loop:

```
from copy import copy

import os

print(os.getcwd())

os.chdir(f"C:\\Users\\{os.getlogin()}\\Desktop\\playarea")

print(os.getcwd())
a = []
for r, d, f in os.walk(os.getcwd()):

for files in f:
    print(files)

    temp = " "
    for i in range(0,len(files)):
        if files[i] == ".":
            temp = copy(files[i:])
            print(temp)
            print(a)
        
            if temp not in a:
                a.append(temp)
print(a)
```

Then variable 'a' wouldn't get overwritten with each loop iteration.